# Date and Time Culture Format based on Country in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, html, date, datetime

I actually have a simple task,
I want to display a date and time (current time) in my website using JavaScript,
but the time can be displayed in a specific ways using two paramaters:

The first parameter is the TimeZone, for example ("+2" or "-7")

The second parameter is the Culture, for example("Japan" or "China" or "En-US")

if the second parameter is "Japan", then it will Display the years,months, and days separated by some Japanese characters,

If the second parameter is "En-US", then it will display: Friday, July 5, 2013

Basically, I can do this in VB .NET with:

```
Dim DateJ as String=""
Dim DateNow as Date=Now
DateJ = Format(GetDateTimeBasedOnTimeZone(DateNow,"+2"), GetCultureFormat("Japan"))
```

the GetCultureFormat function mainly doing this in VB.NET:

```
 Dim CItm As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("Japan")
```

But I can't find a way to do the exact same thing in JavaScript,

I even looked and searched on the internet and even [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)

But so far I can only find how to do the first parameter, which is to change the current time to be based on the TimeZone("+2" or "+7"), but not for the second parameter, which is to display the time based on the Country Culture

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).
You can include your [culture scripts](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/tree/master/lib/cultures) and set your jQuery culture:

```
Globalize.culture('ja');
```

or

```
Globalize.culture('ja-JP');
```

some extra [infos](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#dates) on dates.